# C#: Using String Value as name of Object Reference

Tags: c#, wpf

At the moment, I have multiple textblocks which I want to access according to the name of the string. Look at the example below:

```
    TextBlock test1 = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock test2 = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock test3 = new TextBlock();
    TextBlock test4 = new TextBlock();

    public static void changeValues()
    {
        string name = "test";
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            [name + i].Text = "Wow";
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I am trying to access text1, text2, etc. The reason I am doing this is because the value of "name" could change at any time so I can re-use this code. I can also make "i < 5" be "i < number" and have the method take an int as one of the arguments. The problem of course is that this won't actually work. I need the string name to be a reference to the TextBlock that the name gives. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why not to use arrays instead?

Comment: Arrays of what and for why exactly?

Comment: Do you have problem with the line '[name + i].Text = "Wow"'? If so, you shouldn't access the control like this. Instead try, 
this.Controls[name +i].Text = "Wow";

Comment: The name of a variable is completely arbitrary. It's all reduced to just values or memory addresses in the compiled code. As such, trying to build a "string name" of a variable is not only not possible, but is completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@PetSerAl is saying:

```
var yourBlocks = new TextBlock[]
{
    new TextBlock(),
    new TextBlock(),
    new TextBlock(),
    new TextBlock()
};

foreach (var block in yourBlocks)
{
    block.Text = "Wow";
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `new TextBlock[]` and step through in the debugger. As to your edit about using textblocks defined in XAML, put the names defined in the XAML in the `new TextBlock[] { ... }` instead of creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

How about Dictionary?

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary= 
            new Dictionary<string, TextBlock>();
myDictionary.Add("name1", mytextBlock1);
myDictionary.Add("name2", mytextBlock2);
myDictionary["name1"] = new TextBlock();
var tBlock = myDictionary["name2"];
```

[Detail here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't that be creating a textblock based on a name. This isn't what I wanted to do.